# C# sorting List key value pair by a date string

Tags: c#, .net

### Solved.

The string for the keyvalue pair

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> responses = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

Is like so: 2011-6-8 2:19:0 || url

I sorted the List by using the following:

```
responses.OrderByDescending(s => DateTime.Parse(s.Key.Split(new string[] { " || " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0])).ToList();
```

Thanks for the quick responses everyone.

### Problem:

I have a list that contains a key value pair like so:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> responses = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

The string key will be a concatenated string of a date time stamp, and a url. For example:
2011-6-8 2:19:0 - http://google.com/?q=somesearch

The following sort works to a point, but the day value is sorted by string, not by number (not unexpected).

With this code:

```
responses.OrderByDescending(s => s.Key).ToList();
```

I'll have something like:

```
2011-6-8 2:19:0 - url
2011-6-8 12:18:0 - url
2011-6-7 12:29:0 - url 
2011-6-6 17:42:0 - url
2011-6-6 12:39:0 - url
2011-6-5 10:31:0 - url
2011-6-3 20:53:0 - url
2011-6-21 9:1:0 - url
```

Any ideas on how to sort this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would cast your Key to a DateTime in OrderByDescending Func and use the built in DateTime.Compare to perform the sort.

This doesn't handle errors obviously if the string isn't actuall a valid DateTime but it will do the right thing without any string hacks

```
responses.OrderByDescending(kvp => DateTime.Parse(kvp.Key));
```

Comment: I tool this, and split part of my Key to sort it. I changed the - separator to a || between the date and url. Then simply used the split method. I'll put my answer in the original.

Comment: Re-reading your question I didn't realize that the key was actually concatenated, so yeah, your idea to string split then DateTime.Parse works perfect

Answer (score 3):

Just add leading zeros to your date format:

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Other option (not sure whether you can do it) is to sort records in advance, before converting date to string.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above answers, if you can control the input, you should change it.
If you can't change the key values, I would split the string - re-build it in a better format and sort that.

Maybe something like this could work (you would have to put it back together in order after sorting):

```
Dictionary<DateTime, string> sortableKeys = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
foreach (string key in responses.Keys)
{
   string[] keySplit = key.Split(" - ");
   sortableKeys.Add(DateTime.Parse(keySplit[0], key));            
}
```

Untested... :)

Comment: I do control the data, sort of. What I have built is a page that aggregates several RSS feeds. Now, the key is the date because that's how i want to sort them. However, what if two feeds have the same time stamp. Theres no way to keep them unique other than adding something additional. So in this case I put the url of the source feed in. If you guys can think of a better way to assign a key, feel free to let me know. But I do have this working :).

Comment: public class DateAndUrl { public DateTime Date { get; set; } public string Url { get; set; } }, List<DateAndUrl> responses ....

Answer (score 1):

You should store as a Date/Time structure or have a sortable string with 0 padded month, day, hours, minutes, and seconds (e.g. 2011-06-06 09:21:03)